# Set logging level for specific exception in Log4Net (for Episerver)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, log4net, episerver

How can I configure the logging levels for specific exceptions in [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html)?

Our application is currently generating multiple [WebSocketException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocketexception(v=vs.110).aspx), at the WARNING logging level. We would, however, like to change if from WARNING to INFO to make our logs more readable.

The application is using the [EPiServer Log4Net](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Logging/logging-with-log4net/) package, but the configuration should be the same.

Is this possible to configure from the Log4Net to do from *.config* file, or would one have to handle it in code?

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want to change your logger settings so that it also *includes* INFO ("set it down to INFO") but that would make it *less* readable.   Or, do you want to change your logs so they output as info *instead of* warning (and thus excluded because config is warn only)?

Comment: You can't change the output of a log (from warn to info) via config, that will require a code change.  However, you can exclude logs from your output - however logs are normally generated at class level, rather than a different logger for each exception type. While log4net does have a nice class hierarchy (eg you can switch at namespace or class level) - it all depends on the name of the logger within the code.

Comment: There's nothing Episerver-specific about the log4net configuration in EPiServerLog.config, so the standard documentation applies: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @freedomn-m, I would indeed want to *change* the logging level from Warning to Info. In addition, I also intended to do this via the .config file, which, as you point out, is impossible. If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it unless someone else has a better suggestion.

Comment: @TedNyberg, that is good to know. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: I believe you are not really interested in WebSocketExceptions, so why not filter them out with log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter?

Comment: @MichelvanEngelen, you are entirely right! We will certainly have to look into that!

Comment: It looks like StringMatchFilter would do what you need - remove them when it's on WARN and don't remove them when it's on INFO.  @MichelvanEngelen can you expand on this / link to an SO example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter out any entries you do not want, since WebSocketExceptions are not very interesting:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <stringToMatch value="WebSocketException" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

Note: Log4Net uses indexof when using StringMatchFilter, so you can look for partial strings. Do take in mind that it is case sensitive.

Comment: This looks perfect! We will give it a go, and see if the log entries disappear. :)

Answer (score 1):

With Log4Net This should be as simple as calling the ILog with info instead of warn.

```
Logger.Info("message");
```

instead of

```
Logger.warn("message");
```

Depending on your setup it might be worth making the change in your xml

```
<log4net> 
  <appender name="appenders_name">
  ... other settings
   <root>
       <level value="INFO" />
   </root>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: The question infers this needs to be done in the config (*How can I configure the logging levels*) rather than the code (but it's not that clear tbh)

Comment: I was originally looking for a *.config* setting to control logging levels - as the updated question now should better reflect. Thank you for answering, though.